# Python: unescape "\xXX"

Tags: python

I have a string with *escaped data* like

```
escaped_data = '\\x50\\x51'
print escaped_data # gives '\x50\x51'
```

What Python function would unescape it so I would get

```
raw_data = unescape( escaped_data)
print raw_data # would print "PQ"
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can decode with `string-escape`.

```
>>> escaped_data = '\\x50\\x51'
>>> escaped_data.decode('string-escape')
'PQ'
```

In [Python 3.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python#Version_3.0) there's no `string-escape`, but you can use `unicode_escape`.

From a `bytes` object:

```
>>> escaped_data = b'\\x50\\x51'
>>> escaped_data.decode("unicode_escape")
'PQ'
```

From a Unicode `str` object:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> escaped_data = '\\x50\\x51'
>>> codecs.decode(escaped_data, "unicode_escape")
'PQ'
```

Comment: How do you do this in Python3?

Comment: You can use `unicode_escape`, for `bytes` object, is the same... for `str` objects you can do: `import codecs; codecs.decode('\\x50\\51', "unicode_escape")`... I edited the answer, can someone peer review it?

Answer (score 7):

You could use the 'unicode_escape' codec:

```
>>> '\\x50\\x51'.decode('unicode_escape')
u'PQ'
```

Alternatively, 'string-escape' will give you a classic Python 2 string (bytes in Python 3):

```
>>> '\\x50\\x51'.decode('string_escape')
'PQ'
```

Answer (score 3):

`escaped_data.decode('unicode-escape')` helps?

Answer (score -5):

Try:

```
eval('"' + raw_data + '"')
```

It should work.

Comment: Please, not `eval`; what if raw_data was user input?