# Any clever way to unescape data from JSON string?

Tags: python, celery, web2py

I am sending some `jsonrpc` requests to a `web2py` server, with a `celery` backend. Sometimes, I get errors which I want to analyze. The errors come escaped in the `jsonrpc` reply, so they are not easy to understand. I get something like this:

```
{"version": "1.1", "id": "ID4", "error": {"message": "TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment", "code": 100, "data": ["  File \"/home/myuser1/tmp/web2py/gluon/tools.py\", line 4068, in serve_jsonrpc\n    s = methods[method](*params)\n", "  File \"/home/myuser1/tmp/web2py/applications/mycompany_portal/controllers/activity.py\", line 66, in get_cdr_page\n    invalidate_cache = pars['invalidate_cache'], use_long_polling = pars['use_long_polling'])\n", "  File \"/home/myuser1/projects/new-mycompany-portal/python_modules/pmq_client.py\", line 85, in get_page\n    res = result.get(timeout=10)\n", "  File \"/home/myuser1/.virtualenvs/python2.7.2-mycompany1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py\", line 119, in get\n    interval=interval)\n", "  File \"/home/myuser1/.virtualenvs/python2.7.2-mycompany1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/amqp.py\", line 138, in wait_for\n    raise self.exception_to_python(meta['result'])\n"], "name": "JSONRPCError"}}
```

What I want is to get the `error.data` part of the `jsonrpc` reply, unescape it and display it as a stacktrace. I can do it manually (change `\"` -> `"` and process the `\n`), but I would like to avoid reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: If that's the JSON then the string should "not contain those extra quotes" after running it through a JSON deserializer before extracting the value ..

Comment: that is the text of the reply, before processing it through the json decoder.

Comment: So: `deserilize(json)['error']['message']`? Unless there is a good reason to *not* deserialize it, that would be the way that - in an obvious non-clever way - "avoid[s] reinventing of the wheel".

Comment: With the new title it does not look clever, indeed. But before you actually realize that is just a json encoded string, coming up with the json decoder thing *is* clever. My problem was that the reply I get is not always json (I am doing different kinds of requests), so I was not properly decoding the json in case of errors (I am doing it right if there are no errors, though).

Comment: Yes, hindsight is 20/20 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this raw unparsed JSON? Parse it as JSON:

```
import json
print ''.join(json.loads(yourstring)['error']['data'])
```

Comment: +1 Without further constraints, I'd first deserialize the JSON. (The JSON library already handles all the "tricky" rules.)

Answer (score 0):

Re-edit:

Use:

unquote

http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote

or

unquote_plus

http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote_plus

for unescape-ing HTTP-like data (ie. percentage-escaping)

See this question and answers for more info:

[Unescape Python Strings From HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/780334/1284631)

And, for unescape-ing regular escaped symbols (ie. backslashes), use .decode() (counterpart of .encode()). See these answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10944959/1284631

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9340191/1284631

Comment: @pst: OK, I get it. So you have unquote() for percent and decode() for backslashes.

Comment: I realize that is just json encoded stuff, nothing to do with url encoding.