# Efficient way to translate escaped characters in a parsed string

Tags: python, regex, string, performance, replace

I'm looking for an efficient way to translate escape sequences in a string (Unicode) to target characters. The strings are some parsed language strings read from a file that we want to transform according to the rules: (note:the escaping rules are different to those of python itself)

```
\uxxxx (four hex digits) --> gives the Unicode character with the given code point
\LF \CR \CR+LF  --> '' : a backslash character followed by a line break removes 
                         both of them, where line break is not platform specific.
(For example: "aa\\\nbb", "aa\\\rbb", "aa\\\r\nbb" all gives "aabb")

\f --> FF char
\n --> LF char
\r --> CR char
\t --> TAB char
\C where C is any other *Unicode* character  ---> gives C itself.
  This includes the escaped backslash '\\' sequence, which should be consumed
  first from left to right:

  r'\\\\u0050' --> r'\\u0050'
  r'\\\\\u0050' --> r'\\P'
```

(Basically these rules are somewhat similar to the escaping rules available in many languages for example Perl and Ruby if I'm not wrong)

(Please note: my usage of raw or normal form of strings in the examples is just for
illustration to show how exactly the strings are translated)

Is it possible with such rules to improve on the most naive method of looping through the string and doing lookaheads, appending to a target string in the process.

A somewhat similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919096/mass-string-replace-in-python) offers answers based on splitting and re-joining the string, but I don't think that can be applied here because of the successive escapes issue.

Comment: I don't understand your second pattern matching example at all. What do you mean by "an escape followed by..." - there is no escape. Also, which Python version?

Comment: Py3 only is okay. These are not formal regex patterns, just illustrations of the rule. For example: "aa\\\nbb", "aa\\\rbb", "aa\\\r\nbb" all gives "aabb". I'll try to re-phrase.

Comment: I see. How are you getting these strings? Are you reading them from a file? If so, how come they are raw strings? If they weren't raw strings, it seems most of the job could be done by a simple `print()`, but that can't quite be it...

Comment: We're reading from a file. My usage of raw string or normal strings is just for illustration as suitable.

Comment: We are parsing a language file and want to apply these translations on parsed strings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944907/python-unescape-xxx is quite close to what you need, but not exactly