# Binary String data to Hexadecimal in python

Tags: python, binary, hex

```
binaryValue= '000000000000000011110011'
```

I want to segregate 8 characters and convert that 8 bits to hexadecimal format as the above will have a value of `'0x000x000xf3'`.

I want this value to be printed via python as `'\x00\x00\xf3'`. Please let me know how to achieve this using python. And please let me know what will happen if there is `'\n'` after every binaryValue string at the end of it. How to achieve this also.

Comment: Where are you getting this value from?

Comment: I am getting these output when `for i in range(0, len(hexVal), 8):
    hexString += hex(int(hexVal[i:i + 8], 2))` using this. But I want my output to be as `\x00\x00\xf3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer which I figured out is:

```
binaryString = '000000000000000011110011'
hexString = ''
for i in range(0, len(binaryString), 8):
    if len(hex(int(binaryString[i:i + 8], 2))) == 3:
        tempString = hex(int(binaryString[i:i + 8], 2)).replace("0x", "\\x")
        hexString += "0" + tempString
    else:
        hexString += hex(int(binaryString[i:i + 8], 2)).replace("0x", "\\x")

print(hexString)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like:

```
inputStr = '000000000000000011110011'
n = 8
listOfBytes = [inputStr[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(inputStr), n)]
for i in listOfBytes: 
    print(hex(int(i, 2)))
```

output_:

> 0x0 0x0 0xf3

Comment: But I want my output to be like `\x00\x00\xf3`. Same as your output but in case of 0x0, I want it as \x00. Please help me how to achieve thus

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do this:

```
b = '000000000000000011110011'
h = '\\' + '\\'.join('x' + hex(int(b[i:i + 8], 2)).split('x')[1].zfill(2) for i in range(0, len(b), 8))
print(h) # This will print \x00\x00\xf3
```

Breaking it down as a longer loop to make it more readable:

```
b = '000000000000000011110011'
h = ''
for i in range(0, len(b), 8): # Same as you did
    temp = hex(int(b[i:i + 8], 2)) # Same as you did
    temp = temp.split('x')[1] # to get the last part after x
    temp = temp.zfill(2) # add leading zeros if needed
    h += '\\x' + temp # adding the \x back
print(h) # This will print \x00\x00\xf3
```

I'm guessing you have to use that as unicode and/or convert it to something else? If so, see the answers here: [Python: unescape "\xXX"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944907/python-unescape-xxx/10944965)